# How to use array with SKSpriteNodes

Tags: arrays, swift2

I'm trying to make a guessing game in SpriteKit. My questions are images that I need to display once. I can't understand how to display them properly and only once. I have an array of them:

```
var pics = ["queston1","question2","question3","question4","question5"]
```

For that purpose I tried to show them with textures like that:

```
var pic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "question1")

func setPics() {
pic.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "question1")
pic.name = pic.texture
addChild(pic)
}

Then I put setPics() at didMoveToView and loop through buttons:

case trueButton:
if pic.name == "question1"
//also tried if pic.texture == pic[0] {
print("true")
pic.texture = pic[1]
pic.removeAtIndex[0] //to prevent displaying it another time
// pic.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "question2"
}
if pic.texture == "question2" {
...
```

And so on. It doesn't work. And I understand that I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know how to do it better. This logic kind of worked when I tried to use random instead of hardcoding which question would be the next, but now it's completely wrong. But with random it was another problem. Textures layered on top of each other even though I was removing them from array.
How to make it right?

Comment: `pic.name = pic.texture` does not compile because you cannot assign value of type `SKTexture?` to type `String?`. This is not the only trivial error in your code, please fix them (with the help of the compiler) and then ask a more specific question.